# When passing parameters via the URL, they are not properly decoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, url-encoding

By "not properly", I mean "not", apparently. Try this link, for example:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65941?SearchString=accept+rate

Steps to reproduce:

1. Execute a query with a string parameter (e.g., [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65941/simple-comment-search)) with spaces in it
2. Switch the site by clicking on another site's icon
3. Observe wrong parameter value

As you repeat this, the string "accept rate" becomes:

```
accept rate  
accept+rate
accept%2Brate
accept%252Brate
```

… and so on and so forth.

Comment: Vote to close as off top...wait a second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, seems the parameter values were having a bit of an identity crisis. I've now [made sure](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=8adaf9ef088262ae433cd03be0a521a05ae8da77) they remember who they are.

Pending pull and deploy from waffles.